# JavaScript ES6: Split array into rest and last with destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I just discovered the delightful ES6 destructuring syntax for lists, i.e.

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]

[first, ...rest] = ls
```

which sets `first` to `1` and `rest` to `[2,3]`. However, is it possible to split the list into `rest=[1,2]` and `last=3` using similar syntax?

I didn't have any luck googling it. I tried some obvious guesses for such a syntax (see below), but they all produced syntax errors.

```
[rest..., last] = ls
[...rest, last] = ls
```

I suppose I could do it by reversing the list twice, so an alternate solution to my question would be a constant time list reversal function.

Comment: `...rest` means remaining values. And since you are using it for first argument, it will assign everything there. A simple way to achieve is `var rest = ls.slice(0); var last = rest.pop()`

Comment: All elements except the last one are often called `init`, btw.

Answer (score 9):

What is commonly called "array destructuring" is actually destructuring an **iterable**, of which an array is a special case. The thing about iterables is that they can be infinite, or "lazy". That is the reason that you cannot destructure into some arbitrary number of elements followed by the last one:

```
const [...first, last] = integers();
```

because `integers` could be

```
function* integers() {
  let n = 0;
  while (true) yield n++;
}
```

and then what would `last` be?

Comment: It should be called iterable destructuring from the beginning. Good explanation!

Comment: There's no theoretical problem with a fixed number of assignment targets after the array pattern. Notice that an infinite iterable never terminates destructuring even with a rest pattern, as it does not lazily initialise `rest` with an iterable but does strictly fill an array.

Answer (score -1):

No, this only works on trailing array elements. So, as you said, they way to achieve what you want would be reversing the array first.

Just in case you haven't come across a similar pattern for object, there is one:

```
const {a, ...rest} = {a: "prop1", b: "prop2", c: "prop3"}
```

A great tool to try all this new features out is https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: Right, but why isn't that supported?